Solana keygen create new pubkey on colab
I would try to generate a wallet with seed phrase on colab. But it seem the code won’t work on colab. Is there anyway I can run in on a non local environment?
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1sV5bWCT2mQJUMBhimFyr9-HKP5jmBFcF?usp=sharing
I would like to test how to generating the key by using colab. I have tried other cloud but it seem google colab is the easiest.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
